# Phonegap vertical tab bar / navigation bar

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to implement a vertical tab bar with PhoneGap (for iOS and Android)?
Something like this.
https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController#readme

I am new to Phonegap.  I just heard you can make a horizontal tab bar with NativeControls.